# Сортировать вектор структур

Tags: c++, сортировка, c++11, stl

Отсортировать вектор по одному из полей, используя алгоритмы STL.
По возможности использовать все перегрузки сортировки (фраза, которую я не понял).

```
struct Dot
{
    double x,y,z;
};

std::vector<Dot> numbers = {
    {123.0, 48.55, 0},
    {-128.1, 0, 49.55},
    {0,134.0,-59.1}
};
```

[Здесь](http://purecodecpp.com/archives/3475) пример очень похож на правду, но я не могу свести до моей задачи.

Answer (score 5):

> По возможности использовать все перегрузки сортировки (фраза, которую я не понял).

В C++ функции могут быть перегружены - иными словами несколько функций с одним и тем же именем но разной сигнатурой могут одновременно быть определены в коде, и затем вызваны соответствующим образом.

В данном случае в роли такой функции должна выступать функция из стандартной библиотеки - `std::sort(...)`

Касательно вашей задачи - чтобы сортировать точки по какому-то полю (или координате), компилятору необходим "объяснить" как сравнивать точки (то есть структуры `Dot`) - это можно сделать аж тремя способами:

1. Создать кастомный компаратор, перегрузив оператор `()` вызова функции (устаревший вариант)

   ```
   struct Dot
   {
       double x,y,z;
   };

   std::vector<Dot> numbers = {
       {123.0, 48.55, 0},
       {-128.1, 0, 49.55},
       {0,134.0,-59.1}
   };

   struct pred
   {
       bool operator()(const Dot& dot1, const Dot& dot2)
       {
           return dot1.x < dot2.x;
       }
   };

   int main()
   {
     std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), pred());   
     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
       std::cout << numbers[i].x << " " << numbers[i].y << " " << numbers[i].z << '\n';

     return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Перегрузить оператор `<`

   ```
   //...

   bool operator < (const Dot& dot1, const Dot& dot2)
   {
       return dot1.x < dot2.x;
   }

   int main()
   {
     std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()); 

     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
       std::cout << numbers[i].x << " " << numbers[i].y << " " << numbers[i].z << '\n';

     return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Передать лямбду (раз уж вы указали 11-ый стандарт) в функцию сортировки из `STL`

   ```
   //...

   int main()
   {
     std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [](const Dot& dot1, const Dot& dot2) -> bool
       { 
           return dot1.x < dot2.x;
       }
     );

     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
       std::cout << numbers[i].x << " " << numbers[i].y << " " << numbers[i].z << '\n';

     return 0;
   }
   ```

**P.S.**

Инклюды не писал, чтобы сократить код.